# how to modify the local file in unity3D for mobile using Json

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find how to modify the content of an existing local file in Unity 3D.
My content is JSON so that using key variable, I can easily modify. However I can't find any local file modification on internet.
so can anybody help me out with modification of any file? if possible, using JSON too?
Thank you

BTW I'm using MINIJson.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Mono has an entire library of file manipulation functions. Your question is not specific to Unity 3D.

MiniJSON supports both serialization and deserialization to and from strings.

If you have a specific question about something you have tried and failed, perhaps you could rephrase your original question and include a code sample of what is not working and I can change my answer.